# React form onKeyDown event not working in mobile

Tags: reactjs, forms, onkeydown

```
const handleTags = (e) => {
  if ((e.key === "Enter" || e.keyCode === 13) && e.target.value.trim() !== "") {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent event bubbling
    setTags([...tags, e.target.value.trim()]);
    e.target.value = "";
  }
};
```

```
      <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="tags">Tags</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="tags"
              autoComplete="off"
              placeholder="type a tag and press enter"
              onKeyDown={handleTags}
              id="tags"
              required
              className="form-control"
            />
          </div>
```

This is a function in react where as I type a tag in an input textbox, followed by the enter key, it gets added to the tag state. It works perfectly in desktop but on mobile, when I press the enter key the focus changes from the input text box to another form element and the function doesn't run as expected. only on mobile

Answer (score 1):

This may be linked to the fact that some mobile browsers interpret the "Enter" key differently, especially within forms.

Try blocking the behavior on mobile to see the reaction

```
    const handleTags = (e) => { if ((e.key === "Enter" || e.keyCode === 13) && e.target.value.trim() !== "") {e.preventDefault(); 
if (!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}

setTags([...tags, e.target.value.trim()]);
e.target.value = ""; }};
```

Comment: Replaced the "e.stopPropagation()" line with your code snippet and there was no difference on mobile

Comment: I tried the earlier code in firefox mobile, and it works well. it doesn't work in edge mobile and chrome mobile

Comment: This is a temporary solution and is not suitable for the long term

Try this way : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: I used the code snippet you edited. It works now on all mobile versions, but still shifts focus, I will try using a ref with the code. Thank you